# boost::program_options class field

Tags: c++, oop, boost

I have a problem with boost::program_options

i have a class

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
class imageProcess{
private:
    po::options_description options;
public:
    imageProcess(int argc,char** argv){
        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        this->options = desc;
```

It gives me these errors:

> non-static const member ‘const unsigned int
>   boost::program_options::options_description::m_min_description_length’,
>   can’t use default assignment operator imgproc     line 163, external
>   location:
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp    C/C++
>   Problem non-static const member ‘const unsigned int
>   boost::program_options::options_description::m_line_length’, can’t use
>   default assignment operator   imgproc     line 163, external location:
>   /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp    C/C++
>   Problem use of deleted function
>   ‘boost::program_options::options_description&
>   boost::program_options::options_description::operator=(const
>   boost::program_options::options_description&)’    imageProcess.cpp    /imgproc/src    line
>   20    C/C++ Problem

What should i do to make options field instance of po::options_description?

EDIT:
I know options field is already an instance but is there a way to set the description "Allowed options" after defining this field(po::options_description options("allowed options"); doesnt work too)? And how i should store previously created instances of object into class fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read your errors:

> non-static const member ‘`const unsigned int boost::program_options::options_description::m_min_description_length`’, can’t use default assignment operator
>
> non-static const member ‘`const unsigned int boost::program_options::options_description::m_line_length`’, can’t use default assignment operator
>
> use of deleted function ‘`boost::program_options::options_description& boost::program_options::options_description::operator=(const boost::program_options::options_description&)`’

They indicate that [`boost::program_options::options_description` does not support the assignment operator `operator=`](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2005/09/13723.php) in your version of Boost (actually since v1.33), due to [the `const` member within `options_description`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/options_description.html).

You'll have to — and anyway *should* — initialise your `options_description` instance using the *ctor-initializer*:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
class imageProcess{
private:
    po::options_description options;
public:
    imageProcess(int argc, char** argv);
};

imageProcess::imageProcess(int argc, char** argv)
   : options("Allowed options")
{}
```

The line starting `:` is where your constructor arguments for the member `options` go.